# pnpm config set auto-install-peers true not working with workspaces

Tags: node.js, package.json, pnpm, peer, pnpm-workspace

**I have this configuration below in .npmrc**

The below settings absolutely work fine within the single repo

```
    auto-install-peers=true
    legacy-peer-deps=true
    save-exact=true
    node-linker=hoisted
    link-workspace-packages=deep
```

Where as the same configuration with mono-repo not installing peer dependencies within the workspace project.

Which settings will enable all the peer-dependencies within the sub project to be installed and referred from the same node_modules to avoid missing modules?